# need to use mysql connection within flink MapFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a flink job that need to transform kafka event from type1 to type2. But during the transformation, I need to call query mysql for additional information to construct type2. MysqlConnection is not serializable, could anyone suggest what's a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try make you connection field transient and initialize it in open method or constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Georgy's answer is the simplest approach. For better throughput and resource utilization, consider using [async i/o](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html). The documentation includes an `AsyncDatabaseRequest` example.